# Ember-CLI - Generating a Route and Template

Tags: javascript, routes, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a problem with this code below, not passing the test. Can anyone check if this is right? Thank you for your assistance in advance!

link-> [screen with code from ATOM Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKmWV.jpg)

link-> [screen with test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFzsG.jpg)

Comment: Hello! Can you share the contents of your test and the version of Ember you are using? I don't see anything wrong with your code so far. It is also best to copy and paste your code into the question so others can try to replicate the bug by copying and pasting it into their own apps. Thank you!

Comment: Hi!,

Finally I get solution of this problem …so the solution is to change a value
in package.json file for “ember-data”: “^2.3.0” … on new value “ember-data”: “~2.3.0” next
re-run npm install and start ember server.

Cheers!

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get solution of this problem …so the solution is to change a value in package.json file for “ember-data”: “^2.3.0” … on new value “ember-data”: “~2.3.0” next re-run npm install and start ember server. Cheers!